# Deploying automatically a static website into Azure using Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to azure and I want to deploy automatically a static website into an azure blob storage with bitbucket pipeline yml script. Can someone please mention the process that we need to follow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use BitBucket, but I publish my personal site to Azure blob storage with an [Azure DevOps pipeline](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/). You should be able to use a similar Azure Pipeline, but wire it up to your BitBucket repository instead of Azure Repos. Your tasks should look something like this:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@2
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: .
    azureSubscription: <Your subscription here>
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: <storage account name>
    ContainerName: <Blob storage container here>
```

If you use CDN with your site, you might want to flush the CDN cache so updates become instantly visible:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Purge the CDN cache'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Your subscription here>'
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az cdn endpoint purge --resource-group ''yevster.com'' --profile-name ''<CDN profile name>'' --name <name> --content-paths ''/'''
```

---

Quick update: it looks like [this](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-storage-deploy) is what you're looking for if you want to do it in BitBucket. I haven't tried it. You'll also need to use the [`Azure CLI Run`](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-cli-run) task to flush the CDN cache.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at these two pages:

1. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-microsoft-azure-900820699.html
2. https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-storage-deploy/src/master/README.md

Post back here if you need anymore help,
Max

Comment: Hi @Max Binnewies, yes I have checked the above two Links. But I'm little bit confused in substituting the values of source and destination strings as mentioned in Point 2. Can you please state or mention the source and destination strings in the azure portal along with screenshots if possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Azure account handy to play with atm. "Source" is the path inside your build container, which should default to the root of your repo. To begin with you can just use "." (current directory) and see what it copies. And then iterate from there. For the "destination" (in Azure", have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata